# Executing a list of functions with early termination

Tags: scala

I have the following list of functions that I need to execute in order.

```
val steps: List[() => StepResult] = List(step1 _, step2 _, step3 _)
```

Each step will return a StepResult, which contains the boolean status, and a message:

```
case class StepResult(success: Boolean, message: String)
```

The idea is to execute each step in order, but stop going over the list if any of the steps fails. What would be the best way of doing this?

I can go over each step, and execute it:

```
val results = steps.map { step => step() }
```

But I'm missing the part of stopping if any of the steps fail. Ideally, I should end up with a `List[StepResult]` that I can then inspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a view to run a `map` and a `takeWhile` without iterating through the list twice:

```
steps.view.map(_()).takeWhile(_.success).force
```

Views evaluate lazily, and are really handy when you want to call several methods on a collection but only iterate through it once, or only evaluate its contents once.  Read more about them [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html).  You can accomplish similar functionality by calling `toIterator` or `toStream` instead of `view`, since those collections operate similarly.

For example:

```
val step1 = () => { println("running step1"); StepResult(true, "") }
val step2 = () => { println("running step2"); StepResult(true, "") }
val step3 = () => { println("running step3"); StepResult(false, "") }
val step4 = () => { println("running step4"); StepResult(true, "") }
val steps = List(step1, step2, step3, step4)
steps.view.map(s => s()).takeWhile(_.success).force
```

This will print

```
running step1
running step2
running step3
```

Note that `running step4` is not printed, since, when using `view`, the `map` and `takeWhile` are used in a single loop.  Contrast this with the naive version:

```
steps.map(s => s()).takeWhile(_.success).toList
```

Since this doesn't use `view`, it will run all 4 steps, and print the fourth statement.

If this is a method, you can also use a `foldLeft` together with a nonlocal `return`:

```
def getResults(steps: Seq[() => StepResult]): Seq[StepResult] = 
    (Seq.empty[StepResult] /: steps) { case (soFar, next) =>
        val nextRes = next()
        if (nextRes.success) {
            soFar :+ nextRes
        } else return soFar
}
```

Or recursively, as explained by Ryan's answer.

Comment: This is awesome! Can you explain this a bit more? "Note that running step4 is not printed, since, when using view, the map and takeWhile are used in a single loop"

Comment: @alexBrand Just think of all the operations that follow `view` as being lazy.  They won't evaluate until the view is transformed back to a traditional collection.  So when you call `map` on the view, it doesn't actually execute anything, you're only telling it _how_ to map its elements.  When you call `force` or `toList`, the view knows how to map items to `StepResults` and that it should only take things while `success` is true.  Read more here: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html

Answer (score 1):

You can using recursion:

```
def doIt(steps: List[() => StepResult]): List[StepResult] = steps match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail => 
    val result = head()
    if (result.success)
      result :: doIt(tail)
    else
      result :: Nil
}
```

Comment: This will run a step twice. One while inside if (head().success). And another time calculating the result of pattern matching(head():: doIt(tail))

Comment: Yes, this will run the step twice. But I think this is the right idea here.